# WPF - RelativeSource Binding Problem

Tags: wpf, binding, relativesource

I am trying to create a back button. So i am binding the navigationwindows backstack.

Code:

```
 <Hyperlink Name="back" NavigateUri="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type NavigationWindow}}, Path=BackStack}">
```

Problem:

1. Error: Mode must be specified for RelativeSource.

Update:

It is not navigation to the previous page.

Geetha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `Mode=FindAncestor` to the [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx) Binding :)

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type NavigationWindow}}, Path=BackStack}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. Error has gone but it is not working. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: BackStack is a list, and NavigateUri expects a Uri :) I don't think Hyperlink will be the answer you are seeking.. Check out Buttons and events. Also, check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice.aspx